# How can i load a custom component in another component dynamically in the same view rather than just use its elememt selector in template

Tags: angular, components

For example, if I have written a popup component,and now I want to use it in another component in which case it will be triggered and loaded dynamically in the same view when I trigger a wrong action. But now I find no good way to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to render any custom component in a view.

Comment: It is on the same page and it is just a pop-up box, so I think it may not be a good choice to use routers.

Comment: you can use modal component from angular material or ng-bootstrap